# Using a dropdown menu to send a named row to a function in Excel

Tags: excel

Hey there Stack Overflow,

I was given a Excel Spreadsheet by a fellow gamer tonight, and I decided that I would like to add some basic functionality to it. The spread sheet itself is just a price location matrix. The left column is the name of the commodity and the top column header is the location.

[image: Wow you can just copy and paste these in here now. The future is amazing]

For this reason I can't sort the data which as far as my limited understanding of Excel programmin, precludes VLOOKUP?

So I guess in programming terms I'm looking for a way to make the drop down return a variable that I can then perform a function on, MAX MIN AVG etc. So that way, rather than the user having to scan the matrix for the best prices, they can just select a particularly commodity from a drop down and get the best BUY/SELL Price. I also was hoping to add in a location filter.

I've tried several approaches and I have about 20 tabs open right now. So I started by dismembering the spreadsheet and creating separate BUY/SELL tables, rather than using ranges.

So I created names for each row (Commodity)

[image: Name Manager]

So the idea is that I can create a drop down that selects say a commodity or location which will then allow me to perform a function on the data in that row or column.

So I tried a few different things, like

```
=INDIRECT(MAX(A31))
```

Which returns a #REF error. I also tried messing around with a variety of things like VLOOKUP. I've also experimented witht the create functino using Name a bit buit I wasn't having a lot of luck.

I've also had a quick look at INDEX and INDIRECT. I'm starting to get a little lost to be honest. I also had a look at dependent dropdowns but it didn't seem that I was able to perform functions on them.

I tried google a number of Excel how-tos and I looked pretty hard on here too. I suspect that the answer is out there somewhere but that perhaps I don't know quite exactly what I am searching for, as one might guess from my clumsy title. Given that I have started to get a little lost, I figured I should probably ask for help for a change.

I was able to get a simple MAX function to work by putting it on the far right, and I could probably create discrete entries for each commodity that displays a MAX value, but I was hoping for something a bit more programmatic and doesn't require the user scanning the entire sheet.

If I'm able to perform functions on the groups then I am hoping that I can simply put the price matrices in other sheets and direct the user to a "dashboard" initially so that they only have to select criteria from dropdowns then it returns the information from that.

I understand that this solution is probably overengineered, it's more just a quick personal project to refresh and extend my Excel skills a little bit.

So to summarise, what I am trying to do:

1. Select a value from the leftmost column list via dropdown
2. Send that value to the function
3. Have a function that takes the value and performs an operation on it (e.g. MAX)
4. Return that value to the user.

If there's a better way to do this I am all open to that. You must pardon my distinct lack of Excel skills.

Regards,

Anaryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with an `INDEX/MATCH` inside your `MAX`.

Something like this - change the table name and range reference as needed:

```
=MAX(INDEX(Table1,MATCH(A8,Table1[Commodity],0),0))
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

How to return the column name of the max value in a certain row. Note that if there is more than one instance of the max value, for example if there were two instances of the number `7`, in the `Corundrum` row, that this would only return the column name of the first instance.

```
=INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,MATCH(B8,INDEX(Table1,MATCH(A8,Table1[Commodity],0),0),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I did run into one. How does this work with a MIN function when I am trying to exclude NAs and 0s? I started with  

'=MIN(INDEX(Com_Matrix7,MATCH(A31,Com_Matrix7[Commodity],0),0))'

Which returned and 0 or N/As which doesn't help when you're trying to find the lowest price. So I tried a Min conditonal and it worked on a range,

'=MIN(IF($A$1:$E$7 <>0,$A$1:$E$7))'

which displayed the correct value in the grid but isn't dynamic from the dropdown, just showing the static figure for those coordinates.

I tried the first one but with 

'[Commodity],-1),0))'

Comment: ... but the last only returned #N/A - I'm guessing I have to slot the >0 conditoinal and the match in somewhere but I am not sure how.

Comment: Never mind =MIN(INDEX(Com_Matrix7,MATCH(A31,Com_Matrix7[Commodity],0),0)) just seemed to arbitrairly start working. Probably made a typo or something.

Finally how am I able to check what column that cell is in and return that too? For example if in your pic I select corundum and it returns 7, how can I make it also return column name 'Test'